# Deploy a Grails 2.1.1 application to Tomcat as an exploded war?

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, war, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a Grails app on OpenShift, and I'm trying to avoid pushing a 50MB file across the web for every change.

I created a project at `~/dev/apps/grails/test` to test it

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214138/47633) on SO, I added

```
grails.war.exploded=true
```

to `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`, which caused this folder to be created:

```
/home/sas/.grails/2.1.1/projects/test/stage
```

**how can I tell it to create the exploded war at `~/dev/apps/grails/test/target/test-0.1`?**

copying the folder like this:

```
cp -r /home/sas/.grails/2.1.1/projects/test/stage ~/dev/tomcat/webapps/test-0.1
```

works ok, but I'm trying to automate the whole process to come up with a quickstart script for OpenShift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just had a look at the source code at grails/scripts/_GrailsWarPlugin.groovy

Just had to add

```
grails.project.war.exploded.dir = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}"
grails.war.exploded=true
```

to grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy